# How to convert class method to static method? PDO query

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple query method with constructor:

```
class mysql_a {

public $db;

public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db=$db;
    }

public function find_by_id() {
   $result =  $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2 LIMIT 1')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $result;
   }

}

$found = new mysql_a($db);
$res = $found->find_by_id();
echo $res['username'];
```

How can I make function "find_by_id" static? I mean something like this:

```
public static function find_by_id() {
   $result = self::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2 LIMIT 1')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $result;
}
```

And how do I execute it? I mean how to change this part:

```
$found = new mysql_a($db);
$res = $found->find_by_id();
echo $res['username'];
```

I can't figure it out and its driving me crazy... Any ideas?
Thanks,
Guu.

Comment: Why do you need to make it static?

Comment: Code looks good. No need to make it static. Where does $db come from?

Comment: You need to static $db too for this :) And discard the construct. As statics methods don't have access to $this. Only to self. You need to replace self::$db-> with $this->db-> and remove the static from the function.

Comment: You won't be able to make it static unless you can make $db static, which is impossible because $db is instantiated at run time.

Comment: I'm in agreement, it's find as it is...there's no real benefit to making it static IMO

Comment: You are right, it works fine as it is. Its no benefit to make it static. The thing was that I had this idea to make it static and after I failed it, it was driving me crazy to figure out whats wrong=]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question would be

```
public static function db() {
    static $conn;
    if (!isset($conn)) {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            die '<pre>'.print_r($ex->getMessage(), true).'</pre>';
        }
    }
    return $conn;
}

public static function find_by_id() {
   $result = self::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2 LIMIT 1')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $result;
}
```

You would have to remove your construct function and create the PDO object within the static function db.

You would call like `$found = mysql_a::find_by_id();`

Comment: I would use ` if( !($conn instanceof PDO) )` as check…